# Using C# to connect to online MySQL database - user has no privileges

Tags: c#, mysql, phpmyadmin

**UPDATE:** Contacted the web host for my website and they said

*Remote mysql connections are not enabled on the shared server, you would need a VPS for that.*

Trying to connect to an online database through a C# Windows Form created on Visual Studios.

The database, username and password are correct as I've used them to connect to the database via PHP on the website. The server is correct as I've managed to connect to the hosting directly and upload files to the server successfully.

On the hosting control panel, I've allowed my IP address to be connected via "Remote MySQL".

The User I'm attempting to login in via has all privileges. When I login to phpmyadmin it says the user has no privileges. There isn't a "User Accounts" option at the top.

C#

```
connString = "server=XXX; port=3306; Database=XXX; Uid=XXX; Pwd=XXX;";
try
{
     conn = new MySqlConnection();
     conn.ConnectionString = connString;
     conn.Open();
     MessageBox.Show("Connected");

     DBConnection.Open();
     OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
     command.Connection = DBConnection;
}
catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

I was expecting to connect to the online database, but instead get the following error message in the message box:

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."

I think this is less down to the code and more down to the lack of privileges for the user, but as no users have privileges on the phpmyadmin I am stuck in a loop of needing to grant privileges without having any privileges to do so.

Comment: Remember, users in MySQL have a Domain part. That designates the place that a UserName is allowed to connect from. So you would have to create a user that is allowed to connect to this MySQL from your IP Address

Comment: You would normally use the `root` Super User to allocate new Users and Privilages. Do you have access to the `root` account or some other Admin account provided to you?

Comment: As far as I know there is no Admin account provided. I've raised a support ticket with my host (unlimitedwebhosting). Is there a way to find out? I tried to use "SELECT user, password FROM mysql.users" but it was denied.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Is your server port which 3306 is available for connect from external ip. If not create rule for it

Comment: Thanks for the help. I contacted my hosting and need a VPS hosting instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I connected the hosting provider and they said:

"Remote mysql connections are not enabled on the shared server, you would need a VPS for that."

Comment: You are using "Host' instead of VPS! Contact the host company's support for more information.